# Power BI Fiscal Year % Change

Tags: powerbi

I have a matrix with department and current and prior fiscal year totals.  I'm may be overthinking it, but I can't figure out how to calculate the percent difference between the two years for each department in the matrix.  Right now I only have FY2021 and FY2022 but we'll be adding more FY's in the future but will only display the top 2 FY's.  Below is what the matrix currently looks like.

[image]

Comment: What determines which are the **top 2 FY's**?  What are you using now to display the difference?

Comment: We only have 2 FY's.  At some point I'll need to add filters for that.  I can't wrap my head around how to add the difference.  I can do this all day long in Excel and pivots but can't figure this out right now.

Comment: Why not just add a column with the percent difference for each row (department)?

Comment: That's my issue.  I'm having trouble (or overthinking) how to do the calc in DAX.

Comment: `% Diff = ([fy2022]-[fy2021]) / [fy2021]`.  It is also there as a "quick measure" and will "total" a weighted average.

Comment: Thank you Ron!  Told you I was over thinking it.